# How to retrieve specific value from extracted document via docFilter?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-dhf

I am using JavaScript(&DHF), now I have docFilter-extracted XHTML
data in "extracted" property.
Now, which cts query should I use and how to retrieve "This Value" from FileCreator? Simply, I would like to do: *var filecreator = 'This Value'*

Any advice will be appreciated.

```
"extracted": "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<html 
xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">\n  <head>\n    <meta name=\"content- 
type\" content=\"application/pdf\"/>\n    <meta name=\"filter-capabilities\" 
content=\"text subfiles HD-HTML\"/>\n    <meta name=\"FileCreator\" 
content=\"This Value\"/>\n
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the value of the extracted property is a string of escaped xhtml, you could use [`xdmp.unquote()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp.unquote) to parse it and return an XML object, then use [`.xpath()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/Document.xpath) to select the value of the `@content` attribute of the meta element that has `@name="FileCreator"` and assign it to a variable:

Assuming that your JSON document is `obj`:

```
var fileCreator = fn.head(xdmp.unquote(obj.extracted))
                  .xpath("/*:html/*:head/*:meta[@name='FileCreator']/@content/string()")
```